# NSNumberFormatter Currency displayed differently in iOS 5.1 and 6.x

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I'm currently developing an app that has to display currencies dependant on a certain culture, my code is:

```
NSLocale* myLocale= [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:myCurrency];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setLocale:myLocale];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myNumber]];
```

---

myNumber = 1450.79

myCurrency= @"es-ES" (or @"es_ES")
iOS 5.1: "€ 1.450,79"
iOS 6.0: "1.450,79 €"

myCurrency= @"en-US" (or @"en_US")
iOS 5.1: "$1,450.79"
iOS 6.0: "$1,450.79"

myCurrency= @"de-DE" (or @"de_DE")
iOS 5.1: "1.450,79 €"
iOS 6.0: "1.450,79 €"

As far as I can guess, iOS does not have a locale for es-ES (Spain) in 5.1?