# How to use different currency symbol instead of device local currency symbol?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

I need to give the facility to user that user can use different currency symbol instead of device local currency symbol. For example: If my device language is 'English', then my currency symbol will be '$' but I need to do that my device language will remain 'English' but currency symbol changed to '€'(or any other currency symbol but not '$').

Please do not mark it as duplicate because I need to use different currency symbol instead of device default local currency symbol.

Please give your suggestion regarding this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
```

where currency code is something like "USD", "CAD", "EUR", "GBP", etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it is not solving the requirement. Here is  the scenario:- if we set the currency code "EUR" and try to get the 'currencyFormatter.currencySymbol', then we get "$" as result because our device default language is still 'English' and I need to get a way to get "€" symbol as result.

Comment: In that case, you might have to just remove the currency symbol with `[currencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""]`. Then it should display EUR 24.95 with no symbol. The question then is about decimal vs. comma. Maybe you can set the locale explicitly and get the correct symbol, decimal/comma with `NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];` and then set the locale, but I haven't tried that. Here's an unanswered SO question that might prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545810/nsnumberformatter-currency-displayed-differently-in-ios-5-1-and-6-x